# If f is a function, what does f.x = 1 represent?

Tags: javascript

I found this type of code somewhere. What does x and y represent here?? Are these variables with scope limited to function f ?

```
function f () {

};

f.x = 1;
f.y = 2;
```

Comment: No these are the properties of `f`.

Comment: To add more reasoning on gurvinder372 comment, a function in Javascript inherits is an Object , thus can have properties

Answer (score 1):

Functions in javascript are first class objects, and can be treated as any other object.

```
var a  = {};
a.x = 1;
b.x = 2; // looks normal, right?
```

Objects in javascript are dynamic, and properties can be added to them on the fly, so, as functions are just objects as well, you can add properties to them. The scope of those properties is the same as if you were treating any other object. Those properties do not affect the functions inner scope (there are not present on `this`)

Answer (score 1):

> Are these variables with scope limited to function f ?

These are the properties of `f`'s function object, and **their scope is defined by scope of where `f` is defined** and **where f's reference can be used**.

**Demo**

```js
function f1() {
  function f() {
  };

  f.x = 1;
  f.y = 2;
  return f;
}
var y = f1();

console.log(y.x)// prints 1 since scope of x property depends upon scope of y
```

But since they are not defined in the prototype of `f`, **they can't be inherited**.

**Demo**

```js
function f() {};

f.x = 1;
f.y = 2;
var y = new f();

console.log(y.x) // prints undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case (I've changed the syntax but it's the same thing)

```
var fn = () => { };

fn.x = 1;
fn.y = 2;
```

you're appending 2 properties to your `fn` object. While it IS a `function` and if you do `typeof fn` it will print `'function'` it's an extended `Object` meaning it has properties.

You can check this with `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` method.

Simply call it before `fn.x = 1; fn.y = 2;`

```
var fn = () => {};
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(fn)); // prints ["length", "name", "arguments", "caller", "prototype"]

fn.x = 1;
fn.y = 2;
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(fn)); // prints ["length", "name", "arguments", "caller", "prototype", "x", "y"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Every JavaScript function is actually a Function object.

Function objects are objects which inherit from the `Function.prototype`. So functions are basically objects which can be invoked, hence you can append to them just like any other object.

MDN reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function